# posting to an api with integer parameter not working with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I trying to post to a api with accepts an integer parameter using angular as below

```
 function getDailyErrors() {
            var uri = "/api/users/error-counts/";
            var inData = { numberOfDays : 5}
            return $http.post(uri, inData)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
```

API

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/users/error-counts/")]
        public MultiCategorySeriesDto<int> GetErrorCounts(int numberOfDays=15)
        {
            return _uow.Events.Errors(numberOfDays);
        }
```

for some reasons the API doesn't accept the parameter I passed instead takes the default int parameter. 
**May I know where the mistake is?**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Try using a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int NumberOfDays { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action will take as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/users/error-counts/")]
public MultiCategorySeriesDto<int> GetErrorCounts(MyViewModel model)
{
    return _uow.Events.Errors(model.NumberOfDays);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a POST, try using the `[FromBody]` attribute on the parameter to let the model binder know where to look for the data

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/users/error-counts/")]
public MultiCategorySeriesDto<int> GetErrorCounts([FromBody]int numberOfDays = 15)
{
    return _uow.Events.Errors(numberOfDays);
}
```

Comment: Does it accept optional parameters? because I get the exception `"Optional parameter 'numberOfDays' is not supported by 'FormatterParameterBinding'."`

Answer (score 0):

The below code works fine for me, using the same API code as posted in your question.

```
    global.Himanshu.ErrorServices.factory('errorcountservices', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    return {getDailyErrors: fucntion()  {
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url:/api/users/error-counts/',
                params: {
                    numberOfDays: 5
                },                    
            }).then(function (response) {
                deffered.resolve(response.data);
            },function (response) {
                deffered.reject(response.data);
            })
            return deffered.promise;
        }}
```